# Find text in a file and copy it to another path(linux command)

Tags: linux, terminal, command

I have a lot of html files in the Desktop / crawling folder. In this folder, I want to collect html files that contain the word “dog” and copy them to another folder. Can I use Linux commands?

Comment: Did you already try something? I am pretty sure if you combine some loop, `grep` and `cp` you will get expected result.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
find . -type f -exec grep -q 'dog' {} \; -exec cp -t /other/DestinationFolder {} +
```

Or if you want to keep dir structure, you could try:

```
grep 'dog' . | tar -T - -c | tar -xpC /home/user/DestinationFolder
```